# Outlook doesn't work by changing network from home to corporate

Tags: wireless-networking, microsoft-outlook

my Outlook doesn't work in the corporate WiFi network, but when I use any other network Hotspot or my Home network) everything works fine. So I tried already many different things, but still, have the same issue. If anybody can help me with this I would be appreciated.

Comment: with your Outlook you mean a personal mail account or a company mail account? what is the error? have you checked with your company network admins?

Comment: hi serhiy, you will get a lot of help here but you have not given enough info for someone to understand what your issue might be. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you seeing an error message? Or just no mail received? Or something else. It may be that mail relay is not allowed between your corporate network and your personal ISP. In which case you could resolve it by using a different outgoing mail server. But without knowing exactly what you're seeing, and what your mail setup is, that's only a guess.

Comment: As others mentioned above, to better solve your issue, please provide me with more specific information related to your issue so that we can conduct further researches.

Comment: Ok, I sync my gmail account with Outlook at home Network, then I open Outlook in the corporate network and the state says "Connected" and I can't send and receive any Emails. I used the repair option,  and it tells " Could not connect to IMAP/POP server"

Comment: You should edit your original post and not posting answers. Please check the help section for how to use the platform. Regarding your issue your company is probably blocking access. Check with your IT/Network Security department. As you noted "Could not connect to IMAP/POP server"

Comment: Thank's. I'm a bit confused because the IMAP servers that are used since Gmail is synced to Outlook I can ping, so they aren't blocked? Can I use SARA tool to find out the issue? Thank's a lot

Comment: a working ping does not mean the access to IMAP/POP ports is not blocked. if ping works and Outlook does not connect, theb your company blocks the access to those ports on google. and you already confirmed that when you try to set up from scratch it says no connection. and again, you need to check with you company admins.

Comment: I'll contact the IT admin, and it seems to be a Fortigate firewall filter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I sync my Gmail account with Outlook at home Network, then I open Outlook in the corporate network and the state says "Connected" and I can't send and receive any Emails. I used the repair option,  and it tells " Could not connect to IMAP/POP server". So I already activated an option in Google account settings **Forwarding IMAP and POP servers**
Then I deleted my account from Outlook and when I tried to add It again, it tells that could not connect to the IMAP server.
Could it be encryption or The mail server of the corporate network?
Incoming server-imap.gmail.com  Port 993, SSL/TLS.
Outgoing server-smtp.gmail.com, port 465,SSL/TLS
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exact Error message:
Something went wrong
We couldn't connect to the incoming (IMAP) server. Please check the incoming (IMAP) server settings and try again.